# Rest apis in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, reactjs

I am new to SharePoint but not having any luck. Please correct me if I am wrong on the process so far.

I am using react and need to create a CRUD app in react for SharePoint, so to do this I need to register the app with this link https://yourtenantname.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/appregnew.aspx
and then when I want to send a rest request I send the token I just created. Have tried connecting but getting a 403 error.

Just confused with the process of linking my react app with SharePoint folder recieving and sending data.

Any sugestions would help or articles.

Comment: If you are using React, I would look into using the SharePoint Framework (SPFx) instead.  It's basically built on top of React, so you will be in familiar territory.  Some starter articles [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview) and [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/overview-client-side-web-parts).

Comment: @user98224 Is your SharePoint site modern site if yes SPFx is the way.
If no, then there's another way

Answer (score 1):

@user98244:

You are missing an important step if your question actually represents the steps you’re taking.

After you **register the app** and acquire the Client ID & Client Secret, you need to **grant the app permissions** from the SharePoint Admin console.  Use the GUI, not PowerShell - it’s a lot less typing and only requires a couple clicks.

See Microsoft article [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azureacs).  It gives a nice walk through of how to perform all the steps.  This article has been my go-to when implementing tenant-wide apps - which is infrequent.

**Caveat:**  the app will have complete God access (i.e.: SharePoint Administrator access), so craft your application taking this into account.

**Vote Up If This Article Helped You**